# Emailing Contents of an Order Form to Email Address

Tags: html, forms, email

I am working on creating an order form in a spreadsheet format that customers can select products to buy, and submit it which would send an email to myself of **only** the products selected (meaning the quantity is greater than or equal to 1) with the item name, SKU, quantity, and contact info in an easy to read format. From the examples that I have found, none of them would work with my spreadsheet form. How can I utilize my HTML form to do this? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<TITLE>B2B</TITLE>
<style>
table {
    width:100%;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #eee;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color:#fff;
}
table#t01 th {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
tr { border: none; }
</style>
</head>
<body>


<form action="mailto:aiden.thomas.pyle@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">

<table id="t01">
 <tbody>
     
<tr>
 <th><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=3>Item Description</FONT></th>
 <th>
 <th><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=3>Notes</FONT></th>
 <th><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=3>SKU</FONT> </th>
 <th><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=3>Cost</FONT></th>
 <th><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=3>Quantity</FONT></th>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td><FONT COLOR=RED FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=3>Paper</FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=3></FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=3></FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=3></FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=3></FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=3></FONT></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2>Printer Paper</FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2></FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2></FONT></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="SKU1" value="9195512" disabled="disabled"></align></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="Cost1" value="$6.99" disabled="disabled"></align></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="Quantity1"></align></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2>3-Hole Punch Paper</FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2></FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2></FONT></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="SKU" value="91832" disabled="disabled"></align></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="Cost" value="$9.49" disabled="disabled"></align></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="Quantity"></align></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2>Heavy Card Stock</FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2></FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2></FONT></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="SKU" value="9375882" disabled="disabled"></align></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="Cost" value="" disabled="disabled"></align></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="Quantity"></align></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2>Wrapping Paper (x-mas)</FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2></FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2></FONT></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="SKU" value="9293374" disabled="disabled"></align></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="Cost" value="$3.49" disabled="disabled"></align></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="Quantity"></align></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2>Greeting Cards/env (x-mas)</FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2></FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2></FONT></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="SKU" value="9467119" disabled="disabled"></align></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="Cost" value="" disabled="disabled"></align></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="Quantity"></align></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2>10# Envelopes</FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2></FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2></FONT></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="SKU" value="90382" disabled="disabled"></align></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="Cost" value="$2.99" disabled="disabled"></align></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="Quantity"></align></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2>Legal Envelopes</FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2></FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2></FONT></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="SKU" value="91145" disabled="disabled"></align></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="Cost" value="$1.79" disabled="disabled"></align></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="Quantity"></align></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2>Padded Legal Envelopes</FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2></FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2></FONT></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="SKU" value="90749" disabled="disabled"></align></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="Cost" value="$7.99" disabled="disabled"></align></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="Quantity"></align></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2>Envelope Sealer</FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2></FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2></FONT></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="SKU" value="" disabled="disabled"></align></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="Cost" value="" disabled="disabled"></align></td>
 <td><align=center><input type="text" size="6" name="Quantity"></align></td>
</tr>

<tr>     
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=4></FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=4></FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=4></FONT></td>
 <td><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=4></FONT></td>
 <td><INPUT type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
 <td><INPUT type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td><align=center><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2>Email </FONT><input type="text" size="20" name="email"></align></td>
</tr>
    
<tr>
 <td><align=center><FONT COLOR=BLACK FACE="verdana, sans-serif" SIZE=2>Name </FONT><input type="text" size="20" name="name"></align></td>
</tr>

</tbody>     
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I utilize my HTML form to send an email to myself of only the products selected (meaning the quantity is greater than or equal to 1) with the item name, SKU, quantity, and contact info in an easy to read format?

Comment: Which language are you using to submit your form?

Comment: I am not using anything to submit my form right now, as I don't know how to successfully go about this. If you could push me in the right direction, that would be wonderful. Thanks!

Comment: [This would be a good place to start](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look.

Comment: So, I took a look at that link and some more examples, and I added the email feature to the code, but it did not send anything to my email. I updated the code in my original post if you want to look at it. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance, I really appreciate the help.